# httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/libphp7.so into server: /usr/local/httpd/modules/libphp7.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: php, apache

I use php7.1 in my linux:

I can check it:

```
# php -v
PHP 7.1.16 (cli) (built: Jun 25 2018 08:12:28) ( ZTS )
```

so in my `http.conf`, I add the module:

```
LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so
```

Then I restart the `apache` by `./apachectl restart`, there I get the bellow error:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 154 of /usr/local/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/libphp7.so into server: /usr/local/httpd/modules/libphp7.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2):

I putting this here, so it might help someone. by using this you can install any version of php7.x

This is process to install apache and php7.1 on Centos7

```
yum install -y yum-utils
```

Apache instalaltion

```
yum -y install httpd
```

PHP 7 rpm (which also include php7.1, php7.2 php7.3 php7.4)

```
yum -y install http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
```

use remi-php71 for php7.1 or remi-php72 or remi-php73 or remi-php74 for other php7.x version

```
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php71
```

It will install php version from above enabled repo

```
yum -y install php
```

This will automatically put libphp7.so file in  module folder and solve above problem in question

Answer (score -1):

You need to install Apache's SAPI for PHP.
Install the following packet: **php-apache**
Then restart your httpd server.

Comment: how to install it in CentOS7?